# MSSQL Automatic Merge Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a PC that has a MSSQL database with 800 variables being populated every second. I need that database to merge/backup to a second database on another server PC at least every 10 minutes. Additionally, the first database needs to be wiped clean once per week, in order to save local drive space, so that only 1 week's worth of data is stored on that first database at any given time; meanwhile, the second database keeps everything intact and never gets cleared, only being added upon by the merges that occur every 10 minutes.

To my knowledge, this means I cannot rely on database mirroring, since the first one will be wiped every week. So from what I have gathered, this means I have to have scheduled merges going on every 10 minutes.

I will readily admit I know next to nothing about SQL. So my two questions are:

1. How do I set up scheduled merges to occur from one database to another in 10 minute frequencies?
2. How do I set a database to be scheduled/scripted so that it gets cleared every week?

(Note: both databases are running on ***MS SQL Server 2012 Standard***.)

Comment: the question is to broad, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what a merge means to you?  That is a bit of a loaded term.  Is it an upsert where the destination will get inserts and updates for every table?

Comment: There are a number of ways that this could be accomplished.  The simplest I can think of would be to set the two servers up as linked servers and then write a trigger for each table on server A that would send anything inserted/updated into those tables to server B.  If you can't use linked servers, then an SSIS package on a schedule is probably your best bet.

Comment: Being woefully inexperienced with SQL, I have not yet tried anything yet. That said, I am looking for a means of copying data from the first database over to the other database every 10 minutes. Since each entry is time stamped, it will simply be adding to the second database's existing database.

Comment: @MartianCodeHound You will have to excuse my lack of knowledge on this subject, but what are "linked severs"? Also, what is an "SSIS package"?

Comment: Linked Servers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms188279.aspx  Basically it allows you to run SQL queries on your server that use databases on another server.  SSIS is SQL Server Integration Services.  It's a project type in Visual Studio that allows you to write packages that move data around fairly easily.  It's very powerful, but probably overkill for this.

Comment: These are complex tasks that cannot be done right out of the box and that, to be reliable, need an expert to implement, test and debug.  I recommend that if you do not know how to do these things, then you should hire/contract someone who does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can create a linked server on server A that connects to server B ([Here's a guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx))

Then create a trigger on your table, for example table1:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
ON table1
AFTER INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO ServerB.databaseB.dbo.table1
    select *
    from inserted
```

More on triggers [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

For part 2, you can schedule a job to truncate the table on whatever schedule you would like.  [How to create a scheduled job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(v=sql.110).aspx).
The trigger only fires on Inserts so deleting rows does nothing to the table on server B.

Comment: There are a host of issues with setting something like this up to run reliably for a production environment.  Also, this trigger will not do what the since it merely copies and does not do the "merge" part that was requested.

Comment: One of Karasu's comments clarifies that every entry is timestamped and will just be added to second database so there won't be any updates.  If there are updates that another trigger.  I do agree with you that setting up something of this scale and complexity can have many issues. For example, what happens if communication between server A and server B is interrupted?

Comment: Fair enough on the INSERTs then.

Comment: Just FYI, at 800 changes a sec, adding triggers on top of that will have some serious perf impact.

Comment: Upon creating the example trigger above, and attempting to execute a simple INSERT statement, I receive the following error: `sp_cursor: the value of the parameter 'value' is invalid`

Comment: Can you provide the table schema and some sample data for the table the trigger is on?

Answer (score 0):

How is the purging/deleting of the data happening, via a stored proc? If so, you could also try transactional replication, and replicate the execution of that particular stored proc, but dummy the proc on the subscriber, so when the proc gets replicated and executed on the subscriber, nothing will get deleted/purged.